# controller do not displays in right way

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, view, controller

I have two controllers in my project. The second controller do not displays in right way. If I open it with in browser line - thats ok, but if i pass it by the link in view its not ok. The second controller resembles on 1st.

Controller(s)

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Article extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index()
   {
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $this->load->view('header_view');
    $this->load->view('menu_view');
    $this->load->view('categories_view');
           $this->load->model('mat_model');
           $data = array();
           $data['news'] = $this->mat_model->get_latest();
           $data['latest'] = $this->mat_model->get_latest();
        $this->load->view('useful_sites_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('article_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');

   }
}
```

?>

The view where I have a link:

```
 <?php foreach ($news as $one):?>
 <div id="right">
 <div id="breadcrumb"><a href="">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="">Somewhere</a></div>



      <h1><?=$one['title']?></h1>

      <p>
      <div id="small_img"><?=$one['small_img']?></div>
      <?=$one['description']?>
      </p>
      <div id="">  <a href="<?=base_url()."article/index/".$one['material_id'];?>" class="postinfo2">Читать далее...</a></div>
      <span class="postinfo"> Posted by <a href=""><?=$one['author']?></a> on  
      <?=$one['date']?></span>
      <HR ALIGN="center" WIDTH="70%" SIZE="1px" COLOR="black">

  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I dont have so much reputation to browse images on the site, but i needs it so much, apologize for using otherwise resource
With line in browser:

With the link:

http://s020.radikal.ru/i710/1301/fd/76f313259454.jpg

With the browser line:

http://s020.radikal.ru/i713/1301/4e/a863cd18184d.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "browser line"? or "line in browser"?

Comment: Make sure you're including your css with absolute (not relative) paths.

Comment: And it seems you are talking about 2 controller but there is only one!!

Comment: Mike, there's nothing wrong with CSS using relative paths. /somepath_to_css/file.css is a relative path and will work for a website at any nesting level.

Comment: @AshleySheridan /somepath_to_css/file.css is not relative.. it's absolute. Could you change the location of that file based on the base url? No, because it starts with a slash... which is what OP needs to do.

Comment: ithcy, I mean adress bar. Sorry for my eng, i m not from en-zone.
Suresh Kamrushi, there is no difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>css/style.css">` or whatever the path to your css file

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: Slavenko, I use your type of path.It works.Why only it type is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reply to the comment above...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>css/style.css">
```

is an **absolute path**.

Lets say that your `base_url()` is `'http://www.example.com/'` so the above line will link to your css like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/css/style.css">
```

so no matter which page you're on, the CSS will always be linked to that css file.

On the other hand if you were using **relative paths** like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

on your site root, the css path would be correct. BUT on some other page, for example

```
http://www.example.com/somepage/testurl
```

your CSS would be linked like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/somepage/testurl/css/style.css">
```

which is obviously, wrong.

Try to google relative and absolute paths in html, that should make things a lot clearer.